# Create a sliding CSS drawer that appears after a given amount of time

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make a CSS sliding drawer that appears over the bottom of a page after a few seconds. I've gotten pretty close with the following. I use `transform: translate(100%, 0);` in `#supportroll` to keep the div hidden at the start.

The trouble is after the animation is over, the div disappears. If I remove that initial transform, the div appears on the screen from the start. I've tried using `display` in the keyframes to switch from `none` to `block`, but that keeps the div from appearing or animating at all. What's a good solution to keeping the div from appearing before the `animation-delay` start time?

```
<html>
<body>

      <div id="supportroll">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#supportroll {
 border: 2px solid #60047A;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #012e2f;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 transform: translate(100%, 0);
 animation-delay: 1s;
 animation-play-state: running;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-name: supportanimation;
}

@keyframes supportanimation {
 from {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
 }
 to {
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
 }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1e4zLtm7/1/

Comment: Have you looked at [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), specifically with the property-value of `forwards`?

Comment: What the comment above said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of "hack" the "time period" like this:

```css
#supportroll {
 border: 2px solid #60047A;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #012e2f;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 transform: translate(0%, 0);
 animation-delay: 0s; /* instead of 1 sec */
 animation-play-state: running;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-duration: 6s; /* instead of 5 sec */
 animation-name: supportanimation;
 
 opacity: 1; /* fade-in effect */

}

@keyframes supportanimation {
 from {
  transform: translate(200%, 0);
  opacity:0;
 }
 to {
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="supportroll">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
```